# Apache - Android Cache not update

Tags: php, android, apache, caching

I am making my website cache using this php code

```
$seconds_to_cache = 3600;
$ts = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $seconds_to_cache) . " GMT";
header("Expires: $ts");
header("Pragma: cache");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=$seconds_to_cache");
```

It works on the desktop without problems, but when I open the website from the android browser "cache not update", the browser shows the old content. When I "refresh" Android web browser it shows the new content. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: [*"can I blame caching"*](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/).